# How to sort a two-part linked list using one variable in C++?

Tags: c++, nodes

I am trying to create a linked list that lists the names of people and their birth years. This list should be sorted in ascending order by their birth years after the input is entered. So far, I've sorted the list by years, which is precisely what I want -- but I can't figure out how to move the names when the sorting order changes.

The node class is defined below:

```
class node
{
public:
    string name, value;
    int year;
    node *Next;
}
*head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
```

The input is sorted in ascending order using the following void function:

```
void sort (node *head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        node *min = head;
        node *cur = head -> Next;
        while (cur)
        {
            if ((min -> year) > (cur -> year))
            {
                min = cur;
            }
            cur = cur -> Next;
        }
        int x = head -> year;
        head -> year = min -> year;
        min -> year = x;
        head = head -> Next;
    }
}
```

And it is output to the screen using another void function:

```
void print (node *x)
{
    if (x == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    node *cur = x;
    while (cur)
    {
        cout << cur -> name << " (" << cur -> year << ")\n";
        cur = cur -> Next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

In the above code, `year` refers to birth year and `name` refers to the person's name. This is a problem, because if I entered "Person 1" as someone born in 2000, and Person 2 as someone born in 1995, the output would say that Person 1 was born in 1995 and Person 2 was born in 2000 after the numbers are sorted. Is there a way to sort the years with the names?

Comment: I suggest you should simply swap `name` just like and along to `year`. Why the constraint "using one variable" exists?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your assignment wants you not to move the names of the variables but to relink the nodes in the link list.

Comment: It's better to swap the addresses of the nodes instead of swapping the contents of the nodes. Take a look here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-nodes-in-a-linked-list-without-swapping-data/

Comment: Ah of course, thank you @MikeCAT. Also thank you for the GFG link Harry, I've been looking for something like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also swap `name` when you swap `year`.

You can use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) to swap variables without using temporary variables.

```
#include <algorithm>

void sort (node *head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        node *min = head;
        node *cur = head -> Next;
        while (cur)
        {
            if ((min -> year) > (cur -> year))
            {
                min = cur;
            }
            cur = cur -> Next;
        }
        std::swap(head -> year, min -> year);
        std::swap(head -> name, min -> name);
        // you may also want this
        // std::swap(head -> value, min -> value);
        head = head -> Next;
    }
}
```